# How can I define an external symbol without a seperate sourcefile?

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, external

A very simple class `foo` implements the singleton pattern: (Note line marks for later reference)

```
struct foo{
    //int value_;        //(1)
    static foo instance_;
    static void init(){
        instance_ = foo();
    }
    static foo& instance(){
        return instance_;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) //oddity of VS/Windows
{
    foo::init();
    //auto inst0 = foo::instance();    //(2)
    //auto inst1 = foo::instance_;     //(3)
    return 0;
}
```

When it stays like this, it compiles fine. The following table will show you when a link error occurs:

```
|  (1)  |  (2)  |  (3)  |  error?  |
====================================
|   N   |   N   |   N   |    N     |
|   Y   |   -   |   -   |    Y     |
|   -   |   Y   |   -   |    Y     |
|   N   |   N   |   Y   |    N     |

Y = Yes, N = No, - = doesn't matter
```

The error encountered is:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct foo foo::instance_"
```

Which of course fades away as soon as I move foo into a seperate header and add a source file including the header and defining the external symbol:

```
foo foo::instance_ = foo();
```

Two questions arise:

1. *Why is there no link error when line (3) is the only one used?* My guess would be some kind of optimisation.
2. *How can I resolve this without adding a source file?* using `= foo()` after the declaration of `instance_` doesn't work, as that is only allowed for `const` integral type members.

Comment: For #2: just put the line `foo foo::instance_;` anywhere in that source file, after the definition of `class foo`. You don't need any extra headers or source files. [Like this](http://rextester.com/PHINS8962)

Comment: About #1 - I suspect it's due to this: **3.2/2** `A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is immediately applied.` I'm too lazy at the moment to dig through **5.19**, but my guess is, without any non-static members the copy constructor is trivial and is somehow automatically `constexpr` and so the caveat applies. Since the variable is not `odr-used`, the definition is not required.

Comment: Thank you very much. If rewrote this as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.